# Convert Android App To PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

Is it possible convert a native Android app in to PhoneGap?
There is a script on: http://www.elvenware.com/charlie/development/android/PhoneGap.html which claimed it was possible, however it doesn't seem to have worked, and I am now stuck as to where to go.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible convert a native Android app in to PhoneGap?

You can rewrite it.

There are bits and pieces of stuff that, in theory, could be used by a large development team to try to create an automated Android->HTML5 translator. However, many Android apps could not be translated that way, as they do things that are not presently possible using HTML5, even with the assistance of a hybrid app container like PhoneGap.

> I am now stuck as to where to go

I would recommend that you start writing the PhoneGap app.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently making a solution which can address this specific problem: how to convert existing android native java app to cross platform (Javascript). It includes Java->Javascript compiler, resource compiler (XML->HTML+CSS) and Javascript implementation of Android API. More information about the project and its current status can be found here: https://wellevo.com/android-js/